# Work with an existing database in Cocos2dx v3.2

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a rock. I have an exist database file (db.db3)

1. How can I check if it exists in the device, both in Android and iOS?
2. I just want to open to read the database, not create a new one, how can I do that? When I follow this tutorial, it just creates the new database, not open the exist database. In addition, how to import the sqlite file in Android and iOS?

At this time, I put the db in Resources/db/db.db3. After I use this below code to open the db, I don't know how to copy this db to the phone data both in Android and iOS, so it always creates a new one.

```
bool DBProcess::OpenDB(char *path)
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    std::string dbPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath();

    dbPath.append(path);
    rc = sqlite3_open(dbPath.c_str(), &db);

    if( rc )
    {
      CCLOG("Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      CCLOG("Opened database successfully\n");
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `sqlite3_open` will create if it isn't already there. No need to copy it to a device. If it doesn't exist it gets created. You then execute your SQL and have your tables, rows, etc created that you app needs to run. Not sure why you are appending `path` to `dbPath`..`getWritablePath()` will already put you where you need to be. Just need to add the name of the db.

Comment: "I have a rock." ... I have paper, I win. Hurray!! :)

Comment: if you have paper, I have scissors! :-) What if we played Rock, Paper, Scissor, Lizard, Spock?

Comment: In that case Sheldon wins by default.

Comment: @GameDeveloper: These are my steps
1. Create a sqlite file independently with code (someone do it). I just get a final file.
2. I have to use this file in game and I don't know where to put this file to read. As you mentioned, I always have an available file to read, but I don't know where to put it in resources. At this time, I put the db.db3 in Resources/db/ folder, and when I run game,  device can't find the file, so it always create a new one :(

Comment: you need to put it where `getWriteablePath()` returns for that specific platform. Serious, `std::cout` this and see....

Comment: @GameDeveloper: I solved it by copy file from asset folder to writable folder, then use the file :)